# Allow only 1 app to connect to specific WiFi

Tags: android, android-wifi, restrictions

At my company, we want to restrict Users (having Android Devices) to access only 1 application using Company Internet.

For example, when I'm in the company and I'm connected to the WiFi, I should be able to access only my company's Application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be done using an app. You would use a network proxy or manage the proxy settings on the devices themselves.

Using a WebView you can restrict loading other urls with this code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.contains("*your url here*")) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Apologies for misframing the question.
Could you help with allowing only 1 app to connect on our company wifi?

Comment: Your app doesn't connect to wifi, your device does. You can write your app to only access one url. How are you accessing it? With a webview?

Comment: Yes Will- with webview.

The intent is that we want users to only use company wifi for official purposes- which in this case are websites hosted on our xxx.company.com domains.

Comment: That's super helpful Will! :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Wi-fi network that only permit access to your domain.

That way all users connected in this Wi-fi network will not have internet connection in their apps except the company app.

Comment: Hello @Felipe
Request you to please elaborate on how I can create the wifi network that permits access to only particular domain?